# Why does width stop my ul from centering?

Tags: css, alignment, width, center

[image: 1]

The CSS is below:

```
#RR .rewards-banner-lego .bubble ul {
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 100px;
    column-count: 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

If I add something like `width: 500px;` it adjusts to the side and does not center, how come?

[image: 2]

Comment: You're centering everything inside a smaller width. Get the centering done with its parent if you want the whole container centered instead. Happy to show you a modern flexbox solution if you create a code snippet with markup etc. to reproduce the problem.

Comment: please include all your codes

Answer (score 0):

it could be that `500px` is too small so another way to add the width is by putting `width: 100%;` making your ul the same width as the website (if that's what you're wanting). If it's still not centered then you might try `justify-content: center;` which makes all the items in the element go to the center of it horizontally.